# Errors in loading data from youtube's api

Tags: objective-c, google-api, youtube-api

I am using the `youtube api`in my mobile application but it is not working.
Once i created the iOS key, i tried it and an error popped up :

```
There is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your API key configuration if request from this IP or referer should be allowed.
```

Then i read about it and it turned out i can solve it by creating a browser key with no referrers so this will work.

After i did that , i've tried it and this error popped up :

```
"domain": "usageLimits", "reason": "keyExpired", "message": "Bad Request"
```

What can i do ??? PLEASE help.

Thank you

**EDIT** : Suddenly and out of nowhere, it worked when i tried the url on google chrome, but in my app when i use `NSJSONSerialization`, it returns a null result with this error :

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (Something looked like a 'true' but wasn't around character 0.) {NSDebugDescription=Something looked like a 'true' but wasn't around character 0.}
```

even though the data is not empty.

Comment: Could you share some code?

Comment: take a screen shot of your credentials screen on google developer console. black out the client id number.

Comment: check edited question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working:

The first error just worked by itself, i actually changed nothing.
And the other error worked by appending data together like that :

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [_dataResponse appendData:data];
}
```

and using the `dataResponse`